# Nested object to LI in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

How do you return an individual li from a nested array in javascript?
I would like a, b, c to be

```
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
```

instead of

```
<li>a,b,c,</li>
```

Here's what I'm doing ([also on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/firetiki/8z130asv/2/)):

```js
var spellingList = ["Word1", ["a", "b", "c"], "Word2", "Word3"];
// for loop should run through spelling list array and create list items in "listSpelling"

for (var i = 0; i < spellingList.length; i++) {
  // create a new li
  var newLI = document.createElement("li");
  var indSpellingWord = spellingList[1];

  // grab the spelling list item 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(indSpellingWord);


  // add the spelling list item to the li
  newLI.appendChild(newContent);

  // get the unordered list and add the new li
  var displaySpellList = document.getElementById("listSpelling");
  displaySpellList.appendChild(newLI);
}
```

```html
<div id="theSpellingList">
  <h3>The Spelling List</h3>
  <ul id="listSpelling">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, to avoid accidentally leaving important details out of your question (having them only in the off-site fiddle), please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) so that people don't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Use `i` as an index instead of `1` here: `indSpellingWord = spellingList[1];`. Or do you want to create a nested `ul` element for each array in `spellingList`?

Comment: And sure enough, detail (what `spellingList` is) was hidden off in the fiddle.

Comment: You've said you want separate items for `a`, `b`, and `c`. What about `Word1`, `Word2`, and `Word3`? Include them? Don't include them?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you want to show all the elements in the array you have to flatten your array using [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
var spellingList = [ "Word1", ["a", "b", "c"], "Word2", "Word3" ];
var flattenSpellingList = spellingList.flat();

for (var i = 0; i < flattenSpellingList.length; i++) {
  // create a new li
  var newLI = document.createElement("li");
  var indSpellingWord = flattenSpellingList[i];

  // grab the spelling list item 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(indSpellingWord);

  // add the spelling list item to the li
  newLI.appendChild(newContent);

  // get the unordered list and add the new li
  var displaySpellList = document.getElementById("listSpelling");
  displaySpellList.appendChild(newLI);
}
```

```html
<div id="theSpellingList">
  <h3>The Spelling List</h3>
  <ul id="listSpelling"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Code hidden off in the fiddle makes the question clearer (well, both clearer and less clear). `spellingList` isn' the simple structure one would otherwise assume it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you very much for spotting this. My bad, I didn't check the fiddle.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` and use `Array.isArray` inside a recursive function.`Array.isArray` to check if the current item under iteration is an array. If so then call the same function.

Also use template literals for a clean code

```js
var spellingList = ["Word1", ["a", "b", "c"], "Word2", "Word3"];
let text = '';


function createList(elem) {
  elem.forEach(function(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      createList(item)
    } else {
      text += `<li>${item}</li>`;
    }
  })
  listSpelling.innerHTML = text;
}
createList(spellingList)
```

```html
<div id="theSpellingList">
  <h3>The Spelling List</h3>
  <ul id="listSpelling">
  </ul>
</div>
```